# Maximum square cells in a rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I know this sounds like bin packing but it's a bit different so please read the question to the end.

Given a rectangle of known width and height, I need to divide it into smaller rectangles using column and rows. I'm essentially creating a grid(Think of iPhone's home screen, it's a grid with square icons).

Now the problem(constrain):

1. Cells' have a minimum size(say height > 10 and width > 10)
2. The proportion of the cell needs to be as close to a square(1:1) as possible
3. All cells' dimension need to be **uniform** in the grid.

I'm solving for the number of columns and rows needed to satisfy the requirements above.

Example:

A rectangle of `width=3; height=3` and with a cell minimum size of `width >= 1; height >= 1`

Becomes:

[image]

In this example, column and row is 3 while all cells have a width and height of 1

**UPDATE:**
A very rough solution that works *some of the time*:

```
size = max(cellMinWidth, cellMinHeight)
columns = floor(width/size)
rows = floor(height/size)
```

This fails when the difference between the width and height of the rectangle is big.

Comment: Why does this fail if the difference in dimensions is large?  You might waste some pixels if the divisions do not come out even, but always less than size of them.

Comment: You have to introduce some "glue" into this problem. When the overall width and height are both primes there is no solution  fulfilling your conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by "glue"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us call $w$ and $h$ the width and height of the rectangle. If we start by considering perfectly square cells of size $s \times s$, the maximal area that can be covered is given by the product between the maximal number of packable cells $\displaystyle \lfloor{\frac{w}{s}}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{ \frac{h}{s}}\rfloor$ and the area $s^2$ of each cell. It is not difficult to show that the remaining uncovered area R is given by

$$ R =h \cdot [w\pmod s]+ w \cdot [h \pmod s] - [w \pmod s] \cdot [h \pmod s] $$

For example, covering a $200 \times 50$ rectangle with area $A=10000$ using $7 \times 7$ cells, the maximal number of cells is $\displaystyle \lfloor{\frac{200}{7}}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{ \frac{50}{7}}\rfloor=28 \cdot 7=196$, and the maximal covered area is $196 \cdot 7^2=9604$. The remaining uncovered area, which in this example is $10000-9604=396$, corresponds to

$$R= 50 \cdot [200\pmod 7]+ 200 \cdot [50 \pmod 7] - [200 \pmod 7] \cdot [50 \pmod 7]\\ =50 \cdot 4+ 200 \cdot 1- 4 \cdot 1=396$$

The formula for $R$ showed above, which for $s$ equal to max(cellMinWidth, cellMinHeight) also reflects the residual uncovered area obtained by applying the solution proposed in the OP, explains why this approach works well when $w$ and $h$ are similar, and fails when the difference between $w$ and $h$ is big. In fact, noting that both mod terms can range between $0$ and $s$, we get that the value of $R$ ranges between $0$ and $s(w+h-s)$. So, for a rectangle with given area $A=w \cdot h$ to be covered with cells of size $s \times s$, the condition that minimizes the sum $w+h$ (and that therefore minimizes the upper bound of $R$)  clearly corresponds to the case $w=h$ (this is easily checked by setting $h=A/w$ and noting that $w+h=w+A/w$ has a minimum in $w=\sqrt{A}$). Accordingly, if we vary $w$ and $h$ by keeping their product constant (i.e., if we consider rectangles with constant area and variable proportions), the sum $w+h$ and the upper bound of $R$ progressively increases as the rectangle proportion departs from $1$ and as the difference between $w$ and $h$ becomes larger. This is also visible starting from the same example of a $200 \times 50$ rectangle as above:  covering it with $s \times s$ cells, the value of $R$ ranges between $0$ and  $s(250-s)$, but the upper bound of $R$ decreases to $s(200-s)$ if we consider a $100 \times 100$ rectangle, and raises to $s(1010-s)$ if we consider a $1000 \times 10$ rectangle (in both cases, despite no changes in the rectangle area). This explains why this method leads to a high probability of having a large uncovered area when the difference between $w$ and $h$ is large.

These considerations suggest that, when choosing the value of cell side $s$ to divide a $w \times h$ rectangle in the "best" way, a good idea could be to test all possible values of $s$, starting from the minimal values allowed, and to choose the value that minimizes $R$ according to the formula above. This analysis can be easily and rapidly obtained by a simple algorithm on a PC. Once the value of $s$ that minimizes $R$ has been found, we can also make a minimal variation in the cell size to achieve a $100\%$ covering, by adding to the cell width and height (until now considered equal in our analysis) a small quantity obtained by dividing the residual uncovered edges among all  cells. The formulas for these small final adjustments are $\displaystyle \frac{w \pmod s}{\lfloor {w/s} \rfloor}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{h \pmod s}{\lfloor {h/s} \rfloor}$.  For instance, if we find that in a $90 \times 34$ rectangle the best value for $s$ is $11$, we can initially cover the rectangle with a $8 \times 3$ grid of square cells of size $11$. Then, we can take the remaining edges $90 \pmod {11}=2$ and $34 \pmod {11}=1$ and distribute them among all cells, obtaining a $100\%$ covering using cells with width $11 +\frac{2}{8}=11.25$ and height $11+\frac{1}{3}\approx 11.33$. This keeps a nearly square shape for the cells and allows a complete covering.

Lastly, if we want to find a more rapid method to choose a good value of $s$ that avoids the need of testing all its possible values, it could be more convenient to privilege minimization of the mod term that, in the formula for $R$, is multiplied by the longest dimension of the rectangle. Taking again the same example of a $200 \times 50$ rectangle, to divide it in cells of size $s$ it is convenient to choose a value of $s$ that makes $50\pmod s$ as small as possible (privileging this, rather than minimization of $200\pmod s$), since then this mod term has to be multiplied by $200$. Although this method does not guarantee that the best value of $s$ is found, it might be useful to create simplified, faster algorithms to find "good" values of $s$.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to project a *centered* subdivided square onto a rectangular region via uniform padding as calculated from the difference between the rectangle and calculated square dimensions. This will, in effect, create a table with cell padding in which the centers will be placed your desired imagery:

1. Let ***K*** be ***min***(width, height), the dimensions of the rectangle.
2. Let ***J*** be ***max***(width, height) - **min**(width,height), the total *padding*.
3. Let ***M*** be ***max***(cellMinWidth, cellMinHeight).
4. Let ***G*** be ***K*** / ***M***, the number of columns and the number of rows (square).
5. Let ***P*** be ***J*** / ***G***, which produces the padding amount between either the columns ***or*** the rows (not both; because square dimensions), depending on the orientation mode of the device or the layout needs.
6. Calculate centers of the tiling, taking into account padding and column or row mode, offset by half the width or height of the image dimensions being placed there.

Note: this method can be extended for the floating (padded) dimension by increasing the padding off screen by a minimum of another row or column of size ***M*** + ***P***, which would allow scrubbing (scrolling) on that dimension.